# Getting invalid URL message in expressjs code

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to express.js coding. In my code below i want to access two URLs like http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost:3000/fetch to serve different requests using get method. While accessing the first URL i am able to get the response but while accessing second URL i am getting 404 error. I am unable to figure out the issue, can you please help me out in this.

Below are my files:

*app.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var fetch = require('./routes/fetch');

var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use('/fetch',fetch);
app.use('/', index);

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('SmartBin: Invalid URL');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

modules.export=app;
```

*index.js*

```
var express = require('express');

/* GET home page */
module.exports = (function() {
    var path = require('path');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var db = require('./dbclient');
    db.dbconnection(null,null,null,null,'smartbin',null);
    var router = express.Router();
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        //res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
        db.get('devicereg',{}).then(function(v){
            //for (i=0; i<v.length-1; i++)
                //res.json(v[i]);
            res.json(v);//.end();
        }).catch(function(v){
            console.log('[SmartBin:Error ' + v);
        });         
    });
    return router;
})();
```

*fetch.js*

```
var express = require('express');

/* GET home page. */
module.exports = (function(){
    var path = require('path');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var router = express.Router();
    var db = require('./dbclient');
    db.dbconnection(null,null,null,null,'smartbin',null);
    router.get('/fetch', function(req, res, next) {
            db.get('devicereg',{}).then(function(v){
                res.json(v);
            }).catch(function(v)
                {console.log('[SmartBin:Error ' + v);}
            );
    });
    return router;
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try one of these options:

**1. Minor changes:**

In your `app.js` use the `app.use('/', index)` and `app.use('/', 'fetch')`. Your route is set inside the `index.js` and `fetch.js` files, so it should work, even not having in your `app.js` the code `app.use('/fetch', 'fetch')`.

In your existing code you probably can access http://localhost:3000/fetch/fetch (because you are declaring `/fetch` in `app.js` and then declaring again `/fetch` in `fetch.js` file).

**2. Pass `app` by parameter to the route file:**

In your `app.js`, try to require your route files passing your instance of `app`, instead of `app.use('/', index)` and `app.use('/fetch', fetch)`.

E.g.:

*app.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Comment these lines
//app.use('/fetch',fetch);
//app.use('/', index);

// Add this lines passing the instance of 'app' you've created
var indexRoute = require('./routes/index')(app)
var indexFetch = require('./routes/fetch')(app)
```

In your route files, try to adapt as the following:

**index.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send("This is index");
    });
}
```

**fetch**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/fetch', function(req, res) {
        res.send("This is fetch");
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.